# Download all images from a single directory of a website

Tags: php, javascript, linux, perl, image

I need to get all of the images from one website that are contained all in one folder. Like for instance, (site.com/images/.*). Is this possible? If so, whats the best way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) software. It can download whole sites. Give website address `site.com/images/` and it will download everything in this directory. (if the directory access is not restricted by owner)

Comment: Thank you so much. You save me, friend (y)

Comment: Works very well with  wget -r --no-parent --no-check-certificate  https://xxxxx.png. I add to add "--no-check-certificate".

Answer (score 11):

Do you have FTP access?

Do you have shell access?

With Linux it's pretty easy. Not sure about windows.

```
wget -H -r --level=1 -k -p http://example.com/path/to/images
```

Edit: Just found [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Edit 2: I just saw the PHP tag, in order to create a PHP script which downloads all images in one go, you will have to create a zip (or equivalent) archive and send that with the correct headers. [Here is how to zip a folder in php](http://www.webandblog.com/hacks/zip-a-folder-on-the-server-with-php), it wouldn't be hard to extract only the images in that folder, just edit the code given to say something like:

```
foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    if (!is_dir($key)) {
        $file = basename($key);
        list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $key);
        switch ($ext) {
            case "png":
            case "gif":
            case "jpg":
                $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if the site allows indexing, all you need to do is `wget -r --no-parent http://site.com/images/`

Answer (score 1):

Depends if the images directory allows listing the contents.  If it does, great, otherwise you would need to spider a website in order to find all the image reference to that directory.

In either case, take a look at [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the images a web page is using: if you are using Chrome, you can just press F-12 (or find Developer Tools in the menu) and on the Resources tab, there's a tree on the left, and then under Frames, you will see the Images folder, then you can see all the images the page uses listed in there.

Comment: Has this been renamed SOURCES?